# Complex integration Question

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't really understand how to do an integral like this:

Let C be a square with corners $(1 + i)$ and $(-1 - i)$. Evaluate $\int_C f(z) dz$ where $f(z) = \frac {1}{(2z+1)}$

I can see there's a singularity at $z= -\frac {1}{2}$ inside the contour so I can't use CIT. Not sure what to do from there.

Comment: Or is this a straight application of CIF, where $f(z) = \frac {1}{2}$, hence $=(\frac{1}{2})(2\pi i) = \pi i$?

Comment: Yes, it follows readily from Cauchy's integral formula at $-1/2$, which lies inside the square, applied to the constant hence holomorphic function $1/2$.

Comment: Thanks. The solution is a bit alien to me as it doesn't use CIF, it defines a contour around the singularity and goes from there. I don't understand how that works.

Comment: What is the contour they use?

Comment: The square $(1 + i), (1,-i), (-1,-i),(-1,i)$.

Comment: So that's exactly the same integral. Do you mean they actually compute it by parametrizing the square? Surely this can be done. But that's tedious, compared to CIF.

Comment: No, they did it a different way but it's not something I can explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_C{dz\over 2z + 1} = {1\over 2}\int_{C} {dz\over z + 1/2} = {1\over 2}2\pi i {\rm n}(C; -1/2) = \pi i,$$
where ${\rm n}(C, -1/2)$ is the winding number of the curve $C$ about -1/2.  Note that $C$ makes one trip about $-1/2$ in the positive direction, so this winding number is 1.

Comment: John Conway's *Complex Analysis* explains this nicely.

Comment: Typo: $z+1/2$ and trip around $-1/2$.

Comment: Thanks, I've not seen this so I'll have to look it up.